# Two conditions for nested while loop in Python?

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm a newbie to Python and my upcoming lab requires me to write a code for a collision test of objects (circles) on a plane. For two circles, I'm prompting the user to input values for the x and y coordinates, as well as the radii of both. Currently I have it set up so that if the user neglects to enter a value for any of the three inputs, it returns an error message using a while loop. That works fine.

However, I also want to set it up so that the radius cannot be less than or equal to zero. I have used a nested while loop. This is my code:

```
while c_1_x=="" or c_1_y=="" or c_1_r=="":
    print "Error: please enter a value for each field. If the value is 0, type 0."
    c_1_x=raw_input("Enter the x coordinate of CIRCLE ONE center:")
    c_1_y=raw_input("Enter the y coordinate of CIRCLE ONE center:")
    c_1_r=raw_input("Enter the radius of CIRCLE ONE:")
    while int(c_1_r<=0):
        print "Error: radius of circle must be greater than zero."
        c_1_r=raw_input("Enter the radius of CIRCLE ONE:")
```

After the outer loop has been satisfied, I want it to analyze the inner loop. If the value of the radius is <=0, I want it to return an error message. However, when I run it, it goes on to then next step even after entering values (specifically a value<=0 for radius). I don't want it to go on to the next step until BOTH criteria are met.  How can I do this?

Thank you very much! I appreciate it!

Comment: Change parentheses `while int(c_1_r) <= 0:`!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Although I prefer Martijn's method, this did do what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Your test for positive integers is flawed:

```
int(c_1_r<=0)
```

This converts the *boolean result* of the `<=` operator to an integer. You never convert `c_1_r` to an integer at all, so you are comparing strings against `0` there. This will *always* be false, because in Python 2, numbers are sorted before strings:

```
>>> 'Foobar' <= 0
False
>>> '-10000' <= 0
False
```

Rather than repeat tests for each variable, use a separate function to handle input of *any* of those numbers. Don't ask for another number until all conditions have been met. Use an infinite `while` loop you break out of (either by using `break` or using `return` from a function) when the input satisfies your conditions:

```
def ask_for_positive_number(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a valid positive integer')
            continue
        if number <= 0:
            print('Please enter a valid positive integer')
            continue
        return number

c_1_x = ask_for_positive_number("Enter the x coordinate of CIRCLE ONE center:")
c_1_y = ask_for_positive_number("Enter the y coordinate of CIRCLE ONE center:")
c_1_r = ask_for_positive_number("Enter the radius of CIRCLE ONE:")
```

Since the function will only ever return when a positive integer has been entered, there is no need to test if all 3 variables have values assigned.

Demo of the function:

```
>>> ask_for_positive_number('Y0!: ')
Y0!: -1
Please enter a valid positive integer
Y0!: foobar
Please enter a valid positive integer
Y0!: 42
42
```

Comment: Thank you! After reading your comment and referring to Python's website, it's making sense. This code is a lot less bulky and gets the job done!

Comment: @Chrispy_Chreme Once you do the same thing more than 2 times, it might be a better idea to make a separate function of it, since you will probably use it again.